# How to place ads (PPC's etc.) on my facebook application to earn money?

Tags: facebook, ads

I am a facebook application developer and have made applications in the past. I wanted to know how other developers place ads on facebook applications like the Cityville bar (on top) etc. to earn money. I am able to get substantial users on my application. Is there some code for it or we have to contact someone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook provides a list of approved advertising companies that comply with their ad policy.

http://developers.facebook.com/adproviders/

```
ad:C media
Ad4Game
AdJug
Adknowledge - (Cubics and Super Rewards)
ADTELLIGENCE
Applifier
APP Prizes
appssavvy
Bizmey
Blue Noodle
Casale Media
CPX Interactive
DoubleDing
Fox Networks
Httpool
IndieClick
Jun Group
Lifestreet Media
Live Gamer
MakeMeReach
MATOMY
Mediastay
MediaWhiz
One iota
Paymentwall
Peanut Labs
PubMatic
RadiumOne
RockYou
Rubicon Project
Smowtion
Sometrics
SponsorPay
SupersonicAds
SVnetwork
Tapjoy
EpicSocial
TokenAds
TrialPay
Underdog Media
ValueClick
WildTangent
XTEND
Ybrant Digital
```

Answer (score 0):

Placing ads on facebook application is possible but it depends which ad you are putting. For example, if you want to place google ads, it has something to do with privacy issue of facebook applications. However, I have seen applications putting google ads in facebook applications via iframes eg `<fb:iframe>` fbml tag or normal iframe tag for iframe applications.

On the other hand, you can use services like [offerpal (now renamed Tapjoy)](https://www.tapjoy.com/) to place ads on facebook applications that are also acceptable by facebook.

Comment: any idea of cityville ads in the iframes?

Comment: @D.J.: Well i have not used/seen that app.

Comment: http://apps.facebook.com/phrases_for_fun/ there are two adds : being naughty in header and cityville in footer.